# Access timestamp grouped with a field and aggregated with speed field

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas dataframe of time series, which consists basically in speeds, datetime of the record and the sensor where this record was registered. See the image below:

[image: s]

The fields "sensor_id" and "timestamp5" was grouped, and the "speed", "lane" and "max_speed" were aggregated.

The problem is that I want to use the timestamp5 column to do a Linear Regression and I can't access this field for some reason (this returns a Key Error).

Here is some code:

```py
df_parcial['timestamp5'][0] = df_parcial['datetime'].dt.floor('5min')


df_aggr = df_parcial.groupby(by=['sensor_id', 'timestamp5']).agg({'speed': ['count', 'min', 'max', 'mean', lambda x:
                                                                            x.std(ddof=0), 'sum'],
                                                                   'lane': 'max',
                                                                   'max_speed': 'max'})
```

So `df_aggr.head()` returns the image I published on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

timestamp5 is now a index. Check `df_aggr.columns` and  `df_aggr.index`.

You only need [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df_aggr =( df_parcial.groupby(by=['sensor_id', 'timestamp5'])
                     .agg({'speed': ['count', 'min', 'max', 'mean', lambda x:x.std(ddof=0), 'sum'],
                           'lane': 'max',
                           'max_speed': 'max'})
                     .reset_index()  )
```

Comment: In parts what I need, I did'n't know that fields were treated as indexes, so now I think I can work more properly with the data. Thanks for your help!